# add timeout between get request in a array of promises

Tags: javascript, async-await, timeout, axios, es6-promise

hay
i making tons of requests to api, and i need to control the stream of the requests

i have function that using axios to make the requests and return a promises, and i going true the array and making the request, then i use Promise.all() to finish the requests, without any delay and control, where i can put some control functions to limit the requests before they sent to the api

that my get func:

```
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(`Getting address for ${lat}, ${lng}...`);
            // Make sure we pass lat,lng to the API.
            axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${lng}&result_type=locality&result_type=administrative_area_level_1&result_type=country&key=${apiKey}`)
                .then(response => {
                    return resolve(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    return reject(error.message)
                }).catch(reject => {
                    return reject
                })
        })
    }
```

then i going true the array and using the get func

```
const newData = data.map(async item => {
        let results = ''
        let reqStatus = ''
        if (item.Longitude !== "blank") {
            const req = await getAddress(item.Longitude, item.Latitude).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            reqStatus = req.status
            results = req.data
        } else {
            results = 'blank'
        }
        let newItem = ''
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2))
        console.log(`status: ${reqStatus} ${results.status}`)
        if (reqStatus == '200' && results.status == 'OK') {
            const rstlength = results.results[0].address_components.length
            newItem = {
                ...item,
                //results_from_google: results,  //results.results[0].address_components[0].long_name
                address_1: rstlength > 0 ? results.results[0].address_components[0].long_name : 'blank',
                address_2: rstlength > 1 ? results.results[0].address_components[1].long_name : 'blank',
                address_3: rstlength > 2 ? results.results[0].address_components[2].long_name : 'blank',
                address_4: rstlength - 1 > 3 ? results.results[0].address_components[3].long_name : 'blank'
            }

        } else {
            newItem = {
                ...item,
                //results_from_google: results,  //results.results[0].address_components[0].long_name
                address_1: 'blank',
                address_2: 'blank',
                address_3: 'blank',
                address_4: 'blank'
            }
        }

        return newItem;
    })
```

now how can i delay the requests?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: You might want to [try a sequential `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572) instead of the concurrent `map`ping.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck

```
const limiter = new Bottleneck({
  minTime: 333
});

limiter.schedule(() => myFunction(arg1, arg2))
.then((result) => {
  /* handle result */
});
```